# I have an issue fount in react-router-dom, my react-app not starting

Tags: reactjs

react js is not running

Error in ./src/firebase/config.js
Module not found: 'firebase' in /home/rahul/Documents/new-app/src/firebase

@ ./src/firebase/config.js 7:16-35

Error in ./~/@remix-run/router/dist/router.cjs.js
Module parse failed: /home/rahul/Documents/new-app/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.cjs.js Unexpected token (1169:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1169:8)
@ ./~/react-router-dom/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js 12:125-153

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.